# How to detect a click on a list element?

Tags: javascript

I have this html code:

```
<div id="wordListDiv">
    <ul>
        <li id="word_0">bateau</li>
        <li id="word_1">braguette</li>
        <li id="word_2">bateau</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have a javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', mouseEventsListener);

function mouseEventsListener ( event ) {

    switch( event.target ) {

        case ***HOW_TO_DETECT_CLICK_ON_THE_LI_ELEMENTS***:

            myFunction( parameter );

        break;

    default:
        
        break;

    }

}
```

How can I execute myFunction from within the switch/case statement when the user clicks on a "li" element?

Comment: why not simply register the listener on that element?

Comment: and why you don't check `event.target` / why you need to use switch?

Comment: Hi, I prefer to have all the event management at the same place in my code. I use switch because I have a lot more buttons but I did not include them in this example

Comment: you can check on `target.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code and as mention in above comment you can add more check as per your need

```js
document.addEventListener( 'click', mouseEventsListener);

function mouseEventsListener ( event ) {

    
    switch( event.target.tagName ) {

        case 'LI':
            alert('Clicked LI')
            //myFunction( parameter );

        break;

    default:
        
        break;

    }

}
```

```html
<div id="wordListDiv">
    <ul>
        <li id="word_0">bateau</li>
        <li id="word_1">braguette</li>
        <li id="word_2">bateau</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To track click on every element, you need to add event listener in a loop

```js
    let list = document.querySelectorAll( '#wordListDiv ul li' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
        list[i].addEventListener( 'click', (e) => {
            console.log( e.target.id );
        })
    }
```

```html
<div id="wordListDiv">
    <ul>
        <li id="word_0">bateau</li>
        <li id="word_1">braguette</li>
        <li id="word_2">bateau</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need the case syntax, use this:

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName("li")].forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el)
  el.addEventListener('click', mouseEventsListener);
})

function mouseEventsListener(evt) {
  var index = whichChild(event.target)
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      myFunction("1");
      break;
    case 1:
      myFunction("2");
      break;
    case 2:
      myFunction("3");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function myFunction(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter)
}

function whichChild(elem) {
  var i = 0;
  while (elem.previousElementSibling != undefined) {
    ++i;
    elem = elem.previousElementSibling;
  };
  return i;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordListDiv">
  <ul>
    <li id="word_0">bateau</li>
    <li id="word_1">braguette</li>
    <li id="word_2">bateau</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Otherwise, I would recommend looking at the other solutions.